# Nest needs C wire - Goodman PGB024075-1

Tags: electrical, wiring, hvac, nest

Complete novice here trying to install a Nest thermostat in our new home. I hooked everything up according to the Nest guide, but the thermostat gave a power/battery error message. I've gathered that it needs a C wire, but it doesn't look like one is available from the older outside unit - Goodman PGB024075-1.

Photos of the outside unit wiring and diagrams here: https://photos.app.goo.gl/CqgssCF3EULeR7YY8

Edit: I think I finally found an applicable manual - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RLIEJSde4Kr5889qODMiiCYcrvHgTp0G/view?usp=drivesdk

I've read through a good number of similar posts, and I understand that if no C connecter is available on the board (at least I couldn't find one), I should be able to splice(?) into one of the wires coming out of the 24v side of the transformer (Pic 2). Not the red wire though. If correct, where exactly would I do this?

There are already spare small wires running into the house to the thermostat (Pic 5), so I should just need a short length of extra wire (Google says 18/5?) and to know where to connect it.

Oddly, the two capped white wires at the bottom are seemingly not connected to anything (Pic 5). They appear to run back into the unit somewhere (Pic 6). Unsure if one of those could be used?

Haven't been able to find a manual online, so hopefully the photos of the wiring diagrams inside the panels are helpful.

I'd really appreciate any additional guidance on this!

Comment: Do you have an economiser fitted to your unit?

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure. I can take some additional photos of the outside of the unit tomorrow. Unless there is a better way to tell? Google was not too helpful

Comment: Take photos of the economizer plug (it's part of the control wiring in the unit, and sits in between the Y to the compressor contactor and the Y/Y2 going to the t-stat) and post them here

Comment: I think it's this? Pics 7a and 7b - https://photos.app.goo.gl/CqgssCF3EULeR7YY8. Tried to get two angles since the wires are bunched up against it.

Comment: That's not the connector I'm after, although it may be that your unit lacks it for some reason or another...

Comment: It's pouring rain here, so I won't be able to get more pictures for a bit. I think I finally found an applicable manual though: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RLIEJSde4Kr5889qODMiiCYcrvHgTp0G/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Good find -- that rules out the economizer plug being an issue, at least.  Can you trace where both wires connected to the compressor contactor's coil go...? One of them should connect to the Y wire from your thermostat, while the other's connected to the various C wires in the unit...

Comment: Ok, added photos 8-13: https://photos.app.goo.gl/CqgssCF3EULeR7YY8
A
Pic 8 shows the larger yellow wire that's attached below to the tiny yellow wire going to the thermostat. From that plug, another yellow wire goes down into what's shown in Pic 9. The other yellow wire below that in Pic 9 goes down and outside the unit into some gray tube.A

Comment: Pic 10 shows three white wires that are attached on the other side of where the yellow wire is attached. a goes to a hole in the sidewall just above it (Pic 11). b goes down and then way back into the unit (Pic 12). And c goes up to the transformer (Pic 13)

Comment: Can you get us photos of the thing in the back of the unit wire b goes to?

Comment: Added pics 14-16. Oddly, once it gets towards the back it fades into light blue. And looks like it goes to a plug that's not connected to anything. I checked 6 times XD, 100% sure that's the white wire b. https://photos.app.goo.gl/CqgssCF3EULeR7YY8

Comment: OK, different approach -- do either of the unused white wires at the thermostat-cable-connection location have continuity to the chassis of the unit?

Comment: Added pics 17-18. Looks like they run back to the same empty plug. And they are actually orange and pink - https://photos.app.goo.gl/CqgssCF3EULeR7YY8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You'll need to do a bit of wiring work

Unfortunately, your unit doesn't expose the C terminal in a convenient place, so you'll have to do a bit of wiring to add it.  You'll need a ¼" "piggyback" tab terminal suitable for 18AWG wire like [the Panduit one depicted below](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/panduit-corp/EDV18-250P-Q/298-16710-ND/9491269), a 3' length of 18AWG blue TFFN wire, and a wirenut suitable for 2 18AWG wires for this.

[image: "piggyback" tab terminal]

Crimp the tab terminal onto the 18AWG TFFN, then stuff it down through the grommet in the bottom of the wiring compartment alongside the other thermostat wires. Once that's in place, slide one of the tab terminals off of the C terminal (the one with the three white-ish wires on it) of the 24V transformer in your unit and slide the "piggyback" terminal on where the terminal you removed went, then slide the terminal you removed onto the tab provided by the "piggyback" terminal.  You can then wirenut the other end of that new blue wire to the wire in your thermostat cable you wish to use as a C wire.

Comment: Got it. Will get out to home depot and give this a shot. Thank you, I really appreciate all your help. Have a great rest of your weekend!

Comment: Is it alright to use 18 awg THHN wire? I haven't been able to find anywhere that will cut only a few feet of TFFN

Comment: @MikeSharp -- 18AWG THHN isn't a thing -- any building wire you get in that size will be either TFN or TFFN